# Make, Syntax of Static Pattern Rules, error " *** target pattern contains no '%'. Stop. "

Tags: makefile

I am trying to build mysql-workbench from source (for a 32 bit Fedora 22).
After many attempts and fixes, I got the following error:

```
plugins/migration/CMakeFiles/wbcopytables-bin.dir/build.make:163: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

Line build.make:163 is

```
plugins/migration/wbcopytables-bin: /bin/sh:\ /root/linux-res-6.3/usr/bin/iodbc-config:\ No\ such\ file\ or\ directory
```

Do you see any typo, with respect to Make and its syntax of [Static Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage)? Or am I on a complete wrong track?

Also, is there a way to check corrections of line 163 without to build the entire .rpm (which takes almost 1h)?

m.

Comment: If that is *literally* line 163 of that file then something went wrong generating `build.make` because that's an error string and not anything valid for that context.

Comment: yes, literally. I don't get your point: should that line  be somehow different?

Comment: That line is an **error**. That's an **error message** from whatever built that file that got inserted instead of the intended output. Whatever built `build.make` **failed** to run correctly.

Comment: `make` is complaining because that line is invalid make syntax because the error contents were not supposed to be there. You will get nowhere working on that error because that isn't the problem. You need to find out why `build.make` was generated incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: Ok, where should I look for a culprit? (need to go)

Comment: I have not the faintest idea. Where did that file come from? Was it in the sources? Did CMake build it?

Comment: I'll try again and try to understand. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 2):

As there is not enough information given in the question, this answer is given on the grounds that it is easy to reproduce the error message in a way that appears to emulate what line 168 has in it.

Given a *Makefile* that contains a construct something this:

```
this: that: somethingelse:
        echo the stuff
```

The error message in the question results:

```
$ make this
Makefile:1: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop
```

And further, since the line 168:

```
plugins/migration/wbcopytables-bin: /bin/sh:\ /root/linux-res-6.3/usr/bin/iodbc-config:\ No\ such\ file\ or\ directory
```

looks an awful lot like:

```
this: that: somethingelse:
```

*build.make* rather seems to have been generated by some script that encountered an error and output:

```
/bin/sh: /root/linux-res-6.3/usr/bin/iodbc-config: No such file or directory
```

It would further appear that said script probably for some reason redirected *stderr* onto *stdout* or whatever file descriptor was being used to generate *build.make*, with the result being that the generated file was so damaged as to produce this error.

Of course, all this presupposes much and the question provides far too little contextual information, but certainly this explanation seems plausible.

In a real *Makefile*, one would correct the situation by removing the colons from all but the final target name, but the OP's file is apparently compromised since it is most improbable that the error message was ever intended to be a target name.